# Null properties in objects retrive by mono.block

Tags: spring, rest, post, spring-webflux

I'm doing a post request to a server.
When I ask for a String, the response its OK. But, when I ask for an object, all the properties are sent null.

I have a @ApplicationScoped class where I execute the following code:

```
MyClassDTO dto = client.post()
                .uri("/myUri/someEndpoint")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .body(Mono.just(json.toString()), String.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(MyClassDTO.class)
                .block();
```

When I execute this I recibe all the fields null.

Here is MyClassDTO code:

```
@Data @Builder @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class MyClassDTO {

    private String Error;
    private String ErrorMsg;
    private SdtpProductPriceDTO SDTProductPrice;
    
}
```

Can someone give me a lead on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to be a naming strategy error. Did you try to specify some strategy? @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class) on your dto. Without json it's difficult to understand

Comment: Could you please print what the response body looks like, its impossible for us to help you with the information given.

Comment: @VladimirKrylov Thanks a lot! The naming strategy fix my problem! I usually leave Spring manage that, but this time the case in the properties is aweful.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks for the advice! I'm going to do my posts better next time. Luckly the solution suggested by Vladimir works just fine! Thanks for the feedback!